# Is this good approach to use interface as model in shared component?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have to create shared partial view **Partial1** and it will be used on other screens.
So instead of creating specific model **PartialModel1** for shared component I can   create interface **IPartialModel1**.

Then other screens could implement IPartialModel1
like

```
BigScreenModel1:IPartialModel1
BigScreenModel2:IPartialModel1
```

so in BigScreen.cshtml I can use

```
@Html.Partial("Partial",BigScreenModel1)
```

and on BigScreen2.cshtml

```
@Html.Partial("Partial",BigScreenModel2)
```

Is this good practice ?

Comment: My inclination is "No".  Why wouldn't you want to use the same data object to populate the same partial when it's called from different views?

Comment: Partial view is not related to data. It contains code that enhance tho data grids  from any views with new functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue I have with this approach, whilst it will work, is that you are tying the view model of your partial to that of the encompassing page.

A better approach would be to have the partial view model as a member of the pages view model, like the following:

```
public class BigScreenModel1
{
    public PartialViewModel OtherViewModel { get; set; } 
}

public class BigScreenModel2
{
    public PartialViewModel OtherViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

And then of course:

```
@Html.Partial("Partial", Model.OtherViewModel)
```

On both pages.  This decouples the view models from one another.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was thinking, although you said it far better than I could.  This is the right way to do it.